# Stop bash from expanding $ from command line

Tags: bash

I have a script I am trying to call that needs to have the $ symbol passed to it.  If I run the script as

```
./script "blah$blah"
```

it is passed in fine but then the script calls another program I have no control over which then expands the parameter to just "blah".  The program  is being called by the command program `$@`.  I was wondering if there was a way to prevent the parameter from being expanded when passed to the next script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options involving changing the quoting:

```
./script 'blah$blah'

./script "blah\$blah"
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it is slightly easier to understand than the first one.

Answer (score 5):

- Escape the character `$` with: `\`, e.g.: `"This will not expand \$hello"`
- use single quotes: `'This will not expand $hello'`
- Use a [HERE DOC](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

  `<<'EOF'

  This will not expand $hello

  EOF`

In your case I recommend using single quotes for readability: `./script 'blah$blah'`.

Answer (score 2):

Call using single quotes:

```
./script 'blah$blah'
```

Or escape the `$`

```
./script "blah\$blah"
```